# Missing dependency when installing Canon Pixma MX330 drivers from michael-gruz PPA

Tags: apt, printing, software-installation, canon

I am attempting to install a canon pixma mx330 (multi-function) all-in-one on Ubuntu 14.04.

I found a page with [instructions for installing canon printers](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-drivers-for-canon-printers-pixma-ip-series-on-ubuntu-14-0413-1013-0412-1012-04-linux-mint-16151413-pear-os-87-and-elementary-os-0-2/), and I have followed the instructions to the point of installing the actual driver without any errors.

When I attempt to install the mx330series driver I get the following error message:

```
charles@charles-GN689AA-ABA-m8277c:~$ sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-mx330series
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   cnijfilter-mx330series:i386 : Depends: libtiff4:i386 (> 3.9.5-3~) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

I have downloaded and attempted to install libtiff4, but my system tells me it is already installed.

What steps do I need to take to get the mmx330 driver installed?  Thank you.

Comment: It's looking for the `i386` version, so you installed the i386 version and not the amd64 version, right? `libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_i386.deb`

Comment: There is no libtiff4 in Ubuntu 14.04 http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libtiff4

Comment: Follow [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/392593/224082) answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the solution is both boggus and the package manager forgot how to set dependencies straight, building the package with the correct order on the build dependencies. I've fixed it in my repository `ppa:braiampe/ppaofme` but if you want you want you can download the sources and fix the problem yourself, here's the diff:

```
=== modified file 'debian/control'
--- debian/control  2013-03-17 11:00:10 +0000
+++ debian/control  2014-06-06 00:52:18 +0000
@@ -9,7 +9,7 @@
                libtool,
                libcupsys2-dev | libcups2-dev,
                libxml2-dev,
-               libtiff4-dev | libtiff5-dev,
+               libtiff5-dev | libtiff4-dev,
                libglib2.0-dev,
                libgtk2.0-dev,
                libpopt-dev

=== modified file 'debian/rules'
--- debian/rules    2013-03-17 11:00:10 +0000
+++ debian/rules    2014-06-06 01:37:52 +0000
@@ -262,7 +262,8 @@

    touch configure-stamp

-
+build-arch: build
+build-indep: build
 build: build-stamp
 build-stamp: configure-stamp 
    dh_testdir

=== modified file 'debian/skel/control.common.i386.skel'
--- debian/skel/control.common.i386.skel    2013-03-17 00:45:19 +0000
+++ debian/skel/control.common.i386.skel    2014-06-06 00:55:49 +0000
@@ -2,7 +2,7 @@
 Section: graphics
 Priority: optional
 Maintainer: Canon Inc. <sup-debian@list.canon.co.jp>
-Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 4.0.0), libcupsys2-dev | libcups2-dev, libxml2-dev, libtiff4-dev, automake, autoconf, autotools-dev, libtool, libglib2.0-dev, libgtk2.0-dev, libpopt-dev, ia32-libs [amd64], libc6-dev-i386 [amd64], gcc-multilib [amd64], lib32stdc++6 [amd64], lib32z1-dev [amd64]
+Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 4.0.0), libcupsys2-dev | libcups2-dev, libxml2-dev, libtiff5-dev | libtiff4-dev, automake, autoconf, autotools-dev, libtool, libglib2.0-dev, libgtk2.0-dev, libpopt-dev, ia32-libs [amd64], libc6-dev-i386 [amd64], gcc-multilib [amd64], lib32stdc++6 [amd64], lib32z1-dev [amd64]
 Standards-Version: 3.7.2

 Package: cnijfilter-common

=== modified file 'debian/skel/control.common.ia32.skel'
--- debian/skel/control.common.ia32.skel    2013-03-17 00:45:19 +0000
+++ debian/skel/control.common.ia32.skel    2014-06-06 00:56:12 +0000
@@ -9,7 +9,7 @@
                libtool,
                libcupsys2-dev | libcups2-dev,
                libxml2-dev,
-               libtiff4-dev | libtiff5-dev,
+               libtiff5-dev | libtiff4-dev,
                libglib2.0-dev,
                libgtk2.0-dev,
                libpopt-dev

=== modified file 'debian/skel/control.common.skel'
--- debian/skel/control.common.skel 2013-03-17 00:45:19 +0000
+++ debian/skel/control.common.skel 2014-06-06 00:56:56 +0000
@@ -2,7 +2,7 @@
 Section: graphics
 Priority: optional
 Maintainer: Canon Inc. <sup-debian@list.canon.co.jp>
-Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 4.0.0), libcupsys2-dev | libcups2-dev, libxml2-dev, libtiff4-dev, automake, autoconf, autotools-dev, libtool, libglib2.0-dev, libgtk2.0-dev, libpopt-dev
+Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 4.0.0), libcupsys2-dev | libcups2-dev, libxml2-dev, libtiff5-dev | libtiff4-dev, automake, autoconf, autotools-dev, libtool, libglib2.0-dev, libgtk2.0-dev, libpopt-dev
 Standards-Version: 3.7.2

 Package: cnijfilter-common
```

As you can notice, the only modified lines are adding libtiff5-dev to the build dependencies or inverting the order of the packages to make the 5 version appear first than the 4.

Comment: I'm contacting the package manager by mail, so he can fix the issue.

Comment: Pretty sure the michael-gruz PPA is not maintained any more.

Comment: @bain that's why I included the method to solve the issue in my answer and also PPA in the form of a diff.